# Pine-script counter: how to increment?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to draw some predefined OHLC lines, eg, yesterday's, last week's etc.
I am trying to set the defaults in 1 point increments.
I am also trying to set the labels in incremented horrizontal offsets, so they don't clash.
To do this, I am trying to use a simple counter.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Lines", overlay=true,  max_lines_count = 100)

defline = 4180
hoffset = 3
voffset = -1
counter = 0

// Yesterday
YO = input(defline + counter, "Yesterday's open")
line.new(bar_index, YO, na, YO, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
lab1 = label.new(bar_index + counter + hoffset, y=YO + voffset, text="YO", color=color.blue, style=label.style_none, size=size.small)
label.delete(lab1[1])

counter := counter + 1

YH = input(defline + counter, "Yesterday's high")
line.new(bar_index, YH, na, YH, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
lab2 = label.new(bar_index + counter + hoffset, y=YH + voffset, text="YH", color=color.blue, style=label.style_none, size=size.small)
label.delete(lab2[1])
```

The problem is, the code stops working with the line where the counter is incremented.
If I comment it out, it works fine, but then of course I'd have to set the offsets manually.

I find this very strange that just an incremented counter breaks the code!

Answer (score 0):

You're code doesn't make sense how you have it set up. You have 2 constants (defline and counter) and then as an input your adding them together, even though there is nothing to input since they are already defined.

Instead you should make defline the input and your YO and YH variables use that to add the counter. It works doing this, I incremented the counter by 10 instead of 1 to separate the lines more. You can change that back if you'd like.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Lines", overlay=true,  max_lines_count = 100)

defline = input.int(4180)
hoffset = 3
voffset = -1
counter = 0

// Yesterday
YO = defline + counter
line.new(bar_index, YO, na, YO, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
lab1 = label.new(bar_index + counter + hoffset, y=YO + voffset, text="YO", color=color.blue, style=label.style_none, size=size.small)
label.delete(lab1[1])

counter := counter + 10

YH = defline + counter
line.new(bar_index, YH, na, YH, extend=extend.both, color=color.blue, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
lab2 = label.new(bar_index + counter + hoffset, y=YH + voffset, text="YH", color=color.blue, style=label.style_none, size=size.small)
label.delete(lab2[1])
```

[image: Working Lines]